# Get a list via reflection

Tags: c#, list, reflection

I have some class that contains a List with a type of PropertyInfo:

```
public List<PropertyInfo> Properties {get; set;}
```

And I have an instance of that class, but it is not known which class it is at the run-time. So with that instance, in my case it's called `P`, I need to loop through the upper-mentioned list. Now I can get the value of the property by using:

```
var PropList = P.GetType().GetProperty("Properties").GetValue(this, null)
```

But if I try to loop through it:

```
foreach (var thisProp in PropList) - I get an error.
```

So, is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What's the error? Could you create an interface with `List<PropertyInfo> Properties {get; set;}` as a member, so you don't need reflection?

Answer (score 3):

You have to *cast*:

```
var PropList = P
  .GetType()
  .GetProperty("Properties")
  .GetValue(P, null) as IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>; // notice "as ..."

// Since PropList is IEnumerable<T> you can loop over it
foreach (var thisProp in PropList) {
  ...
}
```

since `GetValue(...)` alone returns `object`.

Comment: That throws the 'The non-generic type 'IEnumerable' cannot be used with type arguments' error

Comment: @Aleksa Kojadinovic: it seems that you should add `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: Instead of passing `this` into the `.GetValue` method, you need to pass in `P`, since you want to get the property on the `P` object, not the `this` object.

Comment: @Mayoor: Nice catch! Copy + Paste from the question is a really evil thing.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code it's clear that

```
 var PropList = P.GetType().GetProperty("Properties").GetValue(this, null)
```

does not return an ienumerable due to which you are getting and error. One possible solution To fix this issue you need to cast it to Ienumerable.

```
 var PropList = P
 .GetType()
 .GetProperty("Properties")
 .GetValue(this, null) as IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>;
```